# Insert in table values from two multiselect boxes in php

Tags: php, mysql

I had a form with select box and was insert on duplicate updating the rows into a table. But now I have changed select box to multiselect box. So how can I insert multiple rows? I tried using the foreach loop twice for each rows. But the problem with that logic is that I can't insert the value from one array being inside another foreach loop. Please help

HTML:

```
//html
<select name="customer_groupings[]"  multiple="multiple">
<option value="-1">-All Groups-</option>
<option value="46" selected="selected">Accessories / Retailer</option>
<option value="47" selected="selected">Counter</option>
<option value="14" selected="selected">Export</option>
<option value="45">Fast Fit</option>
<option value="2">Independent</option>
<option value="44">Internal</option>
<option value="1">National</option>
<option value="19">Other</option>
</select>
<select name="penetration_group[]"  multiple="multiple">
<option value="-1">All</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">Main Supplier</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Not Main Supplier</option>
<option value="3" selected="selected">New Customer</option>
</select>

// there are other form elements as well.
```

PHP:

```
// php
/*
table contact_scripts has the following fields
ID (PK)
branch
customerGroupID
penetrationGroupID
type
message

branch,customerGroupID,penetrationGroupID,type are UNIQUE

*/
foreach ($customerGroupID as $value) {
    $q = $this->reporting->query("
        INSERT INTO
            `contact_scripts` (`branch`, `customerGroupID`, `type`, `message`)
        VALUES
            (-1, {$value}, {$type}, '{$message}')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            message = '{$message}'
    ");
}

foreach ($penetrationGroupID as $value) {
    $q = $this->reporting->query("
        INSERT INTO
            `contact_scripts` (`branch`, `penetrationGroupID`, `type`, `message`)
        VALUES
            (-1, {$value}, {$type}, '{$message}')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            message = '{$message}'
    ");
}
```

Obviously this is not the right way of doing it, therefore, its not working as I want it to.

Comment: Show us the code you've tried so far. Your php and your html.

Comment: code added in the first post...please help I am stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're asking here. Why do you need to access something from the other loop? I don't see anything in your queries that would suggest that. Maybe you need to move one loop inside the other?

```
foreach ($customerGroupID as $cgid) {
  ...
  foreach ($penetrationGroupID as $pgid) {
    ...
  }
}
```